# Random Shuffle error string

Tags: c++, string, random

I am working on a Jumble program. And when the word is printed I get a random number. I get the memory location of the string I tried dereference it but I get word not shuffled and every time its the same string.

```
while(command != "quite")
    {
      string wordr;
      srand(time(NULL));
      int randomnes = rand()%7;
      wordr = word[randomnes];
      random_shuffle(wordr.begin(),wordr.end());
      cout<<word<<endl;
      cin>>command;
      if(wordr==command)
      {
        cout<<"correct\n";
      }
      else
      {
          cout<<"wrong"<<endl;
      }
    }
```

Word is a string array. And before I shuffle the characters if I print the word I get no error.So it something within the line shuffle. But when I tried with a tried something like this

```
string something ="something"
random_shuffle(something.begin(),something.end());
```

It shuffles the word like it supposed to.

Comment: `wordr` is empty. And what is `word`?

Comment: unrelated but `rand()%7` is not really random (very poor distribution), consider the standard `<random>` header. And set the seed once..

Comment: Don't call `srand()` inside the loop, seed the random engine once!

Comment: Look carefully at what you're printing. If you put spaces around the operators, you would see the typo much easier.

Comment: You should avoid use of `random_shuffle`.

Comment: This is not the whole code.I sad for this in the text word is anarry.Wordr is = word[example]

Comment: What you sad between the operators i had trouble whit typing anything with space deleted the thing in front of it